# Crash when deleting dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, delete-operator

my program keeps crashing when I try to delete my dynamic allocated array. When I debug the program this error comes up:

```
 #0 0x47a949    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () (??:??)
#1 0x48a940 std::cerr () (??:??)
#2 0x722924 ?? () (??:??)
#3 0x4010fd __mingw_CRTStartup () (??:??)
#4 0x7729cf34   strerror_s() (C:\WINDOWS\SysWoW64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#5 0x775d0719   ?? () (??:??)
#6 0x775d06e4   ?? () (??:??)
#7 ??   ?? () (??:??)
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numNames;
    cout << "How many names do you want to enter?" << endl;
    cin >> numNames;
    std::string *names = new (nothrow) std::string[numNames];
    if (!names)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not allocate memory";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= numNames-1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name #" << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> names[i];
    }

    for (int start = 0; start < numNames; start++)
    {
        int smallestName = start;
        for (int currentName = start + 1; currentName < numNames; currentName++)
        {
            if (names[currentName] < names[smallestName])
            {
                smallestName = currentName;
            }
        }

        swap(names[start], names[smallestName]);
    }

    cout << endl << "Here is your sorted list: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numNames; i++)
    {
        cout << names[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] names;
        names = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried with both names = 0; and names = nulltptr; and neither of them worked.
I hope you can help me find my problem.
Cheers!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: In your last for loop ... i <= numNames .. should be .. i < numNames

Comment: Works fine when I try it,what values crash it

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, his debugger is the exactly wrong tool to solve this particular problem.

Comment: You really should try [modern C++ techniques](http://ideone.com/fYEbDR).  Makes your life easier when you can see for yourself what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your error isn't because of the delete statement. It is because when you are outputting in the loop `for (int i = 0; i <= numNames; i++)` due to `<=` you are accessing an element which is not available in memory hence the program crashes. To fix this just use `i < numNames`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!